# jRuby error when running rake

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, rake, jruby, jrubyonrails

I run `Rails 4.1.5` with `java version 1.7.0_55` and `jruby 1.7.12`.
When I run any rake command (eg. rake db:create, jruby -S rake db:create) I get this error:

`NameError: missing class or uppercase package name (org.pryrepl.InterceptionEventHook'), caused by (NameError) cannot load Java class org.pryrepl.InterceptionEventHook`
`org/jruby/javasupport/JavaUtilities.java:54:in get_proxy_or_package_under_package'`
`file:/home/ujohndel/.rvm/rubies/jruby-1.7.12/lib/jruby.jar!/jruby/java/java_package_module_template.rb:14:in method_missing'`

PS: I'm new to jRuby.

Comment: are you sure you have the jar containing `org.pryrepl.InterceptionEventHook` in your class path?

Comment: seems as a pry issue ... to confirm try removing it from your *Gemfile*